# How to escape any backslash inside a file using sed

Tags: bash, shell, sed

Hi I have a file which has a string in it that is in an array format and i'm using jq to loop through each index and have some logic depends on the string on each index. However there is a backslash character and jq returns invalid escape character. So I think I need to escape the backlash. How can I do that using sed?

Example:

```
["*","*Cases","*/opt/selenium/tests/src/test/cases","*../../src/test/cases","*01 Login","*/opt/selenium/tests/src/test/cases/01_login.robot","*../../src/test/cases/01_login.robot","*TC001 Verify the login","*<p>If member has clicked 'Remember Me' check box, after the deployment, it's not necessary to input account and password when login. Web do not have the 'Remember Me' function\x3c/p>","*Login button is not visible after 60 seconds"]
```

Comment: Escaping all backslashes is a very blunt approach here, as it will deface potentially valid escape sequences. Your problem is with `\x3c`, which is valid in JavaScript but not in JSON. It makes more sense to replace `\x3c` with `\u003C` (both supposedly represent a `<` character). If possible, fix the source of this poor JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You can escape `/` with `\/` in `sed` like this:

```
sed -i "s#\/#\\\/#g" filename
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: Please add a few sentences to explain what your code is doing, so you can get more upvotes for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote you want to escape any **back**slash (`\`), not slash (`/`). Assuming that the escape character is backslash itself, then the following should do the job:

```
sed -i 's/\\/\\\\/g' filename
```

This can become even shorter:

```
sed -i 's/\\/&&/g' filename
```

but using literals in the replacement instead of the variable `&` is more efficient.

In case you just made a kind of typo, and you want instead to escape slashes with backslashes, then the following command should suffice:

```
sed -i 's|/|\\/|g' filename
```

(Since I used `|` instead of `/`, I don't need to escape the `/` in the replacement.)

Answer (score 0):

The error is probably caused by the escape sequence `\x3c` appearing in one of the string literals.
That is a valid escape sequence in JavaScript (it represents the character `<`), but in JSON it is invalid.
JSON *does* support Unicode escapes, though: `\u003c`.

Apparently you got your input from some kind of JavaScript serializer.
The best solution would of course be to replace that by a proper JSON serializer.
If that is not possible or not practical (for example because it comes from a third party),
then you could use `sed` to replace every `\xnn` with its Unicode counterpart `\u00nn`.

```
sed 's/\\x\([0-9A-Fa-f]\{2\}\)/\\u00\1/g' poorjson.txt
```

Output:

```
["*","*Cases","*/opt/selenium/tests/src/test/cases","*../../src/test/cases","*01 Login","*/opt/selenium/tests/src/test/cases/01_login.robot","*../../src/test/cases/01_login.robot","*TC001 Verify the login","*<p>If member has clicked 'Remember Me' check box, after the deployment, it's not necessary to input account and password when login. Web do not have the 'Remember Me' function\u003c/p>","*Login button is not visible after 60 seconds"]
```

Please note that this is not 100% foolproof.
It does not check if the backslash itself has not been escaped.